# Mongodb data sync between primary and secondary node even when port is closed

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mongodb-replica-set

I have configured mongodb replicaset in aws using 3 ec2's with one primary and 2 secondary nodes. When I insert data on primary node it is getting synced to the secondary nodes which it should. But when I close the port via security group still the data is syncing to the secondary node whose port is closed even though the state in rs.status() in the primary node is stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)" -> for the secondary node(whose port is closed).

I tried this with my secondary node in different subnet public as well as private but its still getting synced.I am new to mongodb and might be doing something wrong. Could someone please suggest something.

Comment: How did you determine that data is still syncing?

Comment: I logged into the mongo shell of these ec2 instances and  the data that I have inserted in the primary node is available on both the ec2 insatances